# Para que sirve pcolormesh() en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto para la universidad de tratamiento de imagenes. Y por más que veo ejemplos o documentación no me queda claro qué hace o para qué sirve, a nivel práctico, la función pcolormesh().

Por ejemplo, en comparación con imshow() qué puedo hacer con pcolormesh?

Comment: Que dice la documentación?

Answer (score 0):

`Pcolormesh` es una función de `Matplotlib` que se utiliza para representar datos en dos dimensiones en forma de malla de colores. Esta función se utiliza para representar conjuntos de datos en los que cada punto en el plano representa una combinación única de dos variables y su color corresponde a una tercera variable.

La función `imshow()` también se utiliza para representar datos en dos dimensiones, pero en lugar de una malla de colores, `imshow()` representa los datos como una imagen bidimensional, con cada píxel correspondiendo a un valor en el conjunto de datos.

En general, `pcolormesh()` es más adecuado para datos con una malla regular de puntos y para representar funciones con una gran cantidad de detalles en el plano. Por otro lado, `imshow()` es más adecuado para representar imágenes con una resolución más alta y para datos con una distribución más irregular de puntos.